# How to make the Youtube's rotating spinner loading screen on Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm making a loading screen on my swing project but I want to use the **Google's rotating spinner as the loading screen**. It is just the loading screen that YouTube uses while it loads the video or it can also be seen when Google Chrome(or any other browser) is loading a webpage (see screenshots). I'm not much good with the graphics class of java however I know the basics. Please suggest me a method to make the loading spinner.

Loading spinner in New Tab of Google Chrome:

[image]

Loading spinner in YouTube:

[image]

Comment: It would less likely be about graphics as it is about threading. Do you know much about threading?

Comment: Check out answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634402/creating-a-nice-loading-animation) question. It has super simple example how to achieve this with `gif` and `ImageIcon`.

Comment: what the attempt you have made on your issue? first show your progress on above, if anything where you got stuck, we definitely help you...

Comment: Essentially it's an arc, you just need to be able to animate the start angle and extent at different rates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the basic idea is, the shape is an open arc.  That is, has a start angle and extends a certain number of degrees to create the edge.

Maybe have a look at [Working with Geometry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for some more ideas.

The idea is then to animate both the start "angle" and the "extent" and different rates.  This gets the "closing" of the circle.  The trick is then the "opening" of the circle when the two ends meet, which is actually the same idea in reverse (kind of ;)). "Opening" the circle again involves recalculating the start position as the difference between the current angle and the extent and then changing the extent to be a fall circle and then letting the animation to play through again.

Because Swing is single threaded AND NOT thread safe, it's important NOT to block the Event Dispatching Thread AND only update the state of the UI (directly or indirectly) from within the content of the Event Dispatching Thread.

The simplest solution is to use a Swing `Timer`, which waits off the EDT, but generates it's notifications within the EDT.

See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private double angle;
        private double extent;

        private double angleDelta = -1;
        private double extentDelta = -5;

        private boolean flip = false;

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    angle += angleDelta;
                    extent += extentDelta;
                    if (Math.abs(extent) % 360.0 == 0) {
                        angle = angle - extent;
                        flip = !flip;
                        if (flip) {
                            extent = 360.0;
                        } else {
                            extent = 0.0;
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

            Arc2D.Double arc = new Arc2D.Double(50, 50, 100, 100, angle, extent, Arc2D.OPEN);
            BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
            g2d.setStroke(stroke);
            g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2d.draw(arc);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

The example also makes use of a `BasicStroke` to give the shape some thickness

Comment: This is an excellent answer, I can basically use it as-is. One small, but important thing should be added, though, I've been hunting it on Linux for hours: Add a `getToolkit().sync()` call at the end of the `paintComponent()` method, otherwise you may experience serious redraw lags when the arc is small.

Comment: @TomášDvořák In some 20 odd years of Java development, I've never had to use `Toolkit#sync`, however, I would recommend putting in the `Timer`s `actionPerformed` method instead

Comment: Yeah, I also wasn't even aware of it's existence until yesterday. However, when really needed, it seems to cause a lot of woes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458711/3220468, https://stackoverflow.com/q/4074284/3220468 . It probably only manifests itself on Linux when only a small portion of the screen is updated, so it was totally confusing to see the spinner choppy when the arc was short and then suddenly smoothing up.

Comment: Somebody once [told me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077372/jseparator-dashed-style/74657060#comment131784160_74657060) that it's not necessary to call `g.create()` in your `paintComponent` method.

Comment: @CardinalSystem No it’s not “necessary”, but there are many good reasons for doing it, especially when dealing with transformations and I do out of habit - a lot less surprises. I also had issues in the past with the rendering hints been maintained and applied to subsequent components in the paint pass - not as pretty as that sounds

Comment: Well, I just learned something new :)

Comment: @CardinalSystem The important thing is to make use you also call `dispose` before the method exists.  In complex paint implementations I may even call create/dispose when passing the context to subsequent calls, so any modifications they make can be contained to the caller, but again, as needs maybe

Answer (score 0):

I expanded a little on [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer)'s answer to create a more modular "plug-and-play" component for my own purposes. Thought I'd share:

```
public class ProgressSpinner extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Dimension size;
    private int actualSize;
    private int halfSize;
    private int thickness;

    private double angle;
    private double extent;

    private double angleDelta = -1;
    private double extentDelta = -5;

    private boolean flip = false;
    private boolean running = false;

    private Timer timer;

    public ProgressSpinner(int size) {
        this(size, 2);
    }

    public ProgressSpinner(int size, int thickness) {
        this.actualSize = size;
        this.halfSize = this.actualSize / 2;

        size += thickness;
        this.size = new Dimension(size, size);
        this.thickness = thickness;

        this.timer = new Timer(10, this);
    }

    public void startAnimation() {
        if (!this.running) {
            this.timer.start();
            this.running = true;
        }
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        if (this.running) {
            this.timer.stop();
            this.running = false;
            super.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (!this.running)
            return;

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        // Center the animation in case a
        // layout manager resizes this component.
        Rectangle bounds = g2d.getClipBounds();
        int x = (bounds.width / 2) - this.halfSize;
        int y = (bounds.height / 2) - this.halfSize;

        Arc2D.Double arc = new Arc2D.Double(x, y, this.actualSize, this.actualSize, angle, extent, Arc2D.OPEN);
        BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(this.thickness, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
        g2d.setStroke(stroke);
        g2d.draw(arc);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.angle += this.angleDelta;
        this.extent += this.extentDelta;
        if (Math.abs(this.extent) % 360D == 0) {
            this.angle = this.angle - this.extent;
            this.flip = !this.flip;
            extent = this.flip ? 360D : 0D;
        }
        super.repaint();
    }

}
```