# Case of the confounding key press caper

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, jnativehook

## Background

Developing a rudimentary, open-source keyboard and mouse on-screen display desktop application for screen casting, called [KmCaster](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/kmcaster):

[image: Screen Casting Preview]

The application uses the [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/) library to receive global keyboard and mouse events, because Swing's [Key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) and [Mouse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) listeners are restricted to receiving events directed at the application itself.

## Problem

When the application loses focus, the user interface shows intermittent key presses, rather than every key press. Yet the console shows that the application has received every key press.

## Code

A short, self-contained, compileable example:

```java
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;

import static java.util.logging.Level.OFF;
import static java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger;
import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater;
import static org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen.*;
import static org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText;

public class Harness extends JFrame implements NativeKeyListener {

  private final JLabel mLabel = new JLabel( "Hello, world" );
  private int mCount;

  public void init() {
    getContentPane().add( mLabel );

    setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    setAlwaysOnTop( true );
    pack();
    setVisible( true );
  }

  @Override
  public void nativeKeyPressed( final NativeKeyEvent e ) {
    final var s = getKeyText( e.getKeyCode() );
    System.out.print( s + " " + (++mCount % 10 == 0 ? "\n" : "") );

    invokeLater( () -> mLabel.setText( s ) );
  }

  public static void main( final String[] args ) throws NativeHookException {
    disableNativeHookLogger();
    registerNativeHook();

    final var harness = new Harness();
    addNativeKeyListener( harness );

    invokeLater( harness::init );
  }

  private static void disableNativeHookLogger() {
    final var logger = getLogger( GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName() );
    logger.setLevel( OFF );
    logger.setUseParentHandlers( false );
  }

  @Override
  public void nativeKeyReleased( final NativeKeyEvent e ) {}

  @Override
  public void nativeKeyTyped( final NativeKeyEvent e ) {}
}
```

The code above produces a small window that, when run, demonstrates the problem:

[image: Harness Screenshot]

Be sure to type into any other window to see the perplexing loss of key presses within the demo application.

## Environment

- OpenJDK version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14, 64-bit
- XFCE
- Arch Linux
- JNativeHook 2.1.0

## Details

JNativeHook runs in its own thread, but using `invokeLater` (or `invokeAndWait`?) should issue the UI update on Swing's event thread.

The call to `disableNativeHookLogger()` isn't relevant, it merely keeps the console clean when running the demo.

## Console Output

Here is the console output when the application has focus:

```
Shift I Space A M Space I N S I 
D E Space T H E Space A P P 
L I C A T I O N Period
```

Here is the console output when the application loses focus:

```
Shift I Space A M Space O U T S
I D E Space T H E Space A P
P L I C A T I O N Period
```

So it's clear that no keyboard events are missing when `nativeKeyPressed` is called, regardless of whether the application has focus. That is, neither JNativeHook nor its event bubbling via JNI appears to be the culprit.

## Question

What needs to change so that the `JLabel` text is updated for every key press regardless of whether the application has focus?

## Ideas

Some items that help include:

- Call `getDefaultToolkit().sync();` to flush the rendering pipeline explicitly.
- Call `paintImmediately( getBounds() )` on the label.

The first item seems to make a huge difference, but some keys still appear to be missing (although it could be that I'm typing too quickly). It makes sense that preventing the rendering pipeline from merging paint requests avoids loss of key strokes.

## Research

Resources related to this issue:

- https://pavelfatin.com/low-latency-painting-in-awt-and-swing/

Comment: *although it could be that I'm typing too quickly* - what happens if you use a JTextArea and append each string as it is received? ( or use a JLabel with label.setText( label.getText(...) + s )Do you see all the text or are characters actually being lost? In your example you always set the text so you will only ever see the last character, so yes if could be as a result of merging painting requests. I don't see a solution for that.

Comment: Would a JTextArea/append change the nature of the test, Heisenbug-style? (I tried and all the characters show up, which isn't surprising since they show up in the console.) Pavel's post, at the end, describes how `sync()` prevents collapsing `paint()` calls; those paint calls can only be collapsed if the net result would be equivalent to having made only the final `paint()` request---a condition not met by appending text.

Comment: The problem is that even if you force the repaint individually the painting can happen so fast that you won't see both results. What you can try is to invoke `mLabel.paintImmediately(...)`, this will paint the component without adding the request to the RepaintManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `sync()` using the default toolkit:

```java
  @Override
  public void propertyChange( final PropertyChangeEvent e ) {
    invokeLater(
        () -> {
          update( e );

          // Prevent collapsing multiple paint events.
          getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        }
    );
  }
```

See the [full code](https://github.com/DaveJarvis/kmcaster/blob/master/src/main/com/whitemagicsoftware/kmcaster/EventHandler.java#L113).